# Play Framework and JPA

Tags: jpa, playframework

testing Play framework and JPA.

I eclipsify my very simple test application. Import the project in eclipse and confirm that the play jar file is in my eclipse java build path: C:\play-2.0.2\repository\local\play\play_2.9.1\2.0.2\jars\play_2.9.1.jar

in my simple Item entity class, I import play.db.jpa.Model which my entity should extend

Here, eclipse is not be able to resolve the class!

Notice, the following jar file DOES NOT include the Model class - which I understand is essential in order to integrate with PLAY with JPA.

play_2.9.1.jar -> play\db\jpa\Model

the jpa only includes the following:
    TransactionalAction$1.class
    JPA.class
    TransactionalAction.class
    Transactional.class
    JPAPlugin.class
    JPA$1.class

what am I missing? do i include a wrong jar in my path?
where is Model.class??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to `import play.db.ebean.*;`, Play 2.0 uses Ebean for the Model extension.

Documentation can be found http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/JavaEbean

Comment: If you would like to extend the Model class yes, the current project I am working on I do not have the luxury of doing it this way as I do not have access to the .java files, but from what I can tell the ebean route would make life a bit easier.

Comment: Ok, now it just fails due to:    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: "The default EbeanServer has not been defined? This is normally set via the ebean.datasource.default property. Otherwise it should be registered programatically via registerServer()".  Two things though, this wiki https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/JavaJPA shows that its possible to integrate hibernate with play2.0, in my case i'd prefere that rather than ebean.

Comment: I would recommend posting another question so you could accurately describe the issue you're running into, and since I believe the original has been answered already.

Just saw your edit, yes I'm using Hibernate as well rather than Ebean so it is possible. That is the link I used as a reference so it should be of help to you.